# How to show scrollbar when the inner content is aligned to bottom?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, the 'outer' and the 'inner' like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/WVd9Q/2/

[HTML]

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <p id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[CSS]

```
    .outer {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        position:absolute;
        overflow-y:scroll;
        z-index: 100;
    }
  .inner {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        width:100%;
        min-width:400px;
        max-width:800px;
        margin: auto;
    }
```

As you can see, the outer covers whole page and the inner is aligned to bottom.
But when you click the [make it long] button to make the inner long, the outer doesn't show a scroll-bar.
It shows the scroll-bar if I change *bottom:0* to *top:0* in the *.inner* as I expected.

How can I show the scroll-bar of the outer with bottom-aligned inner?

**appended**
Okay, [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WVd9Q/23/) is the final form that I wanted. Thank you!

[HTML]

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="content">
            <p id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[CSS]

```
body {
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
.outer {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}
.inner {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
.content {
    min-width:400px;
    max-width:800px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: since .inner is absolutely positioned, it doesn't have a size within .outer. on .inner do "max-height: 100%; overflow-y: scroll" and remove the scroll from outer. Also, supply an example/fiddle/codepen

Comment: I see. max-height was what I missed. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: glad to be of help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WVd9Q/14/).

As Doxick mentioned what I did was to remove overflow-y from your outter, set a height for your inner div, and add the overflow-y:sroll to it as well.

```
.outer {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}
.inner {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:100%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    max-height:100%;
    min-width:400px;
    max-width:800px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Looks simpler, Thank you for the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WVd9Q/22/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="scroll">
            <p id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <button id="longButton" type="button">make it long!</button>
            <button id="shortButton" type="button">make it short!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    overflow-y:hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
/*Opera Fix*/
 body:before {
    content:"";
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    width:0;
    margin-top:-32767px;
}
.outer {
    width:100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
.scroll {
    width:100%;
    max-height:260px;
    z-index: 9999;
    position:relative;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
.inner {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-width:400px;
    max-width:800px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    clear:both;
}
/*display*/
 .scroll {
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.inner {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I voted @Doxick 's solution, but it's also helpful, when I need that design. Thanks.